# How do I add gem 'minitest' to my test helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, minitest

I am new to Ruby on Rails and testing. When I run `rake test` I get the following error:

```
/Users/jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/backports
/uri/common_192.rb:53: warning: already initialized constant WFKV_
/Users/jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/turn-0.8.3/lib/turn/autorun
/minitest.rb:14:in `<top (required)>': MiniTest v1.6.0 is out of date. (RuntimeError)
`gem install minitest` and add `gem 'minitest' to you test helper.
    from /Users/jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib
/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
```

I did `gem install minitest` and now it says to *add gem 'minitest'* to my test helper. Is this `test/test_helper.rb`, and if so, how do I "add" minitest?

Comment: have you read this? http://www.rubyinside.com/a-minitestspec-tutorial-elegant-spec-style-testing-that-comes-with-ruby-5354.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link, I am reading through it and it is explaining everything better.

Comment: Thanks for adding your solution!

Comment: Add your solution as an answer to your own question for future use...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Edit your Gemfile so that the gem is specified under the test group, like so:

```
group :test do
  gem "minitest"
end
```

*(Posting the solution that the OP edited into the question, but did not post as an answer)*

Comment: If you're pulling your hair out over it, try going back to Minitest 4.5.0. I could not get 5.0.4 to work.

Comment: I've done this, and it still says that I need to add it to my test helper

Answer (score 3):

uninstall your minitest first. gem uninstall minitest.

if you are using turn make sure the version is less 0.8.3

put those code to your bottom of your Gemfile

```
group :test do
  gem 'turn', '< 0.8.3'
  gem 'minitest'
end
```

then run

```
bundle install
```