# Rails "MiniTest v1.6.0 is out of date. (RuntimeError)" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.1.1 on Windows 7. I tried running a `rake test` command, but I keep getting this error:

```
`<top (required)>': MiniTest v1.6.0 is out of date. (RuntimeError)
`gem install minitest` and add `gem 'minitest' to you test helper.
```

I already tried using `gem install minitest`, I also added `gem "minitest"` to my gem file and ran `bundle install`. Nothing worked. I tried running `bundle exec rake test`, that failed too. I'm still getting the same error. My gem file has this:

```
group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
  gem "minitest"
end
```

Any ideas where I've gone wrong? Full pastie of error: http://www.pastie.org/3214398

Running `gem query` returns this for minitest: `minitest (2.10.1, 1.6.0)`

I have found that several people have [had this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870074/what-do-i-do-with-this-error-when-i-run-tests-in-rails) before, but none of the posted solutions have worked for me.

Comment: I have seen this link hope it will help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779467/how-do-i-add-gem-minitest-to-my-test-helper

Comment: @paim, thanks for chiming in. I saw that to. As you can see my gem file has `gem "minitest"` already. It made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen two solutions to this: the first is `gem uninstall minitest --version 1.6.0`, and that'll make sure the only minitest you have is the most up-to-date one.

The second would be `bundle exec rake test` - that will run rake test using the gems specifically in your Gemfile.

Comment: One thing I missed - in order for the `bundle exec` method to work, you'll need to specify in your Gemfile `gem "minitest", ">= 2.10"` so it would ignore the old minitest.